# linear algebra find basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$W = \{(a, b, a + b, c) \mid a, b, c ∈ \mathbb R\}$

and $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$

then I have to find basis of $W$.

but I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Would you be able to rewrite each vector $(a,b,a+b,c)$ as a linear combination $a(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)+b(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)+c(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)$? (I.e., can you think of some numbers which could be used in places where I wrote $\cdot$?)

Answer (score 2):

Observe that we have three independent variables $a,b,c$ so as to create the subspace $W \subset \Bbb{R}^{4}$ (As if we know $a,b,c$ then we know all the 4 coordinates of $W$).

So we now have that the dimension of $W =3$.

So for basis as per Martin Sleziak's comment, we write

$(a,b,a+b,c) = a(1,0,1,0) +b(0,1,1,0) + c(0,0,0,1)$

And hence the basis of $W $ is $\{(1,0,1,0),(0,1,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$.